# Fuel mass required to heat a room

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws

> A room in a house measures 3.7 m × 4.7 m × 4.0 m. Assuming no heat or material losses, how many grams of natural gas (methane, CH4) must be burned to heat the air in this room from 15.0 degrees C to 25.0 degrees C. Assume that air is 78% N2 and 22% O2.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you have any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

Comment: Related: [How much does a light heat the air around it?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/35534/7951)

Answer (score 1):

In the first step, we calculate the energy that is needed
to heat the room by ten degrees.
To do that, you need the heat capacity of air:
$C_\text{air} = 1210~ \text{J} \cdot \text{m}^{-3}\cdot \text{K}^{-1} $
This is the energy that is needed per volume unit to increase the temperature by one Kelvin (i.e. one Degree).
To increase the temperature by $\Delta T = 10 ~\text{K}$ for a volume of $V_\text{room}=\text{3.7 m}\cdot\text{4.7 m}\cdot\text{4.0 m}=69.56 ~\text{m}^3$  you would thus need an energy of
$$ E = C_\text{air}\cdot  V_\text{room} \cdot \Delta T = 
1210~ \text{J} \cdot \text{m}^{-3}\cdot \text{K}^{-1} \cdot 69.56~\text{m}^3 \cdot 10~\text{K} \approx 842~\text{kJ}$$
We can now calculate the amount of methane that needs to be burned to get that energy. For this, we take the enthalpy of combustion $\Delta H_\text{comb}$:
$$\Delta H_\text{comb} = −882.0 ~\text{kJ/mol} \equiv 55.1~\text{kJ/g}$$
Thus, we calculate the mass of methane to be
$$ m_\text{methane} = 842/55.1 ~\text{g} = 15.3~\text{g}.$$
So about 15 g of methane would be needed to increase the temperature of that room by 10 degrees. By the way, 15 g methane correspond to a volume of about 20 L.

Comment: Is that the upper heating value of methane or the lower heating value?

Comment: The upper heating value.